identity.5.azurestaticapps.net - SmartScreen for Edge reports as unsafe
How can I prevent SmartScreen for edge reporting "identity.5.azurestaticapps.net" as unsafe, since this is what is used by Azure Static Web Apps for Single Sign On etc.
